# react alert showing Uppercase

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hiSw.png)i am using the  react-alert but its showing the message in Uppercase.
Any pointer how can i ged rid off all caps?
Example: For the code below, the message shows as "TEST MESSAGE" instead of "Test Message"

Code:--------

```
this.alertOptions = {
  offset: 50,
  position: 'top right',
  theme: 'dark',
  time: 5000,
  transition: 'scale'
};
```

msg.info('Test Message', {
        time: 0,
        type: 'info',
        theme: 'light',
        icon: 
      });

Comment: You need to override only the `text-transform` property. Write the line of css `.react-alerts .alert .message { text-transform: initial; }`

Comment: @peter Great .Thanks

Comment: also 
(1)i am trying to apply background color through custom css but its just taking the color in center not for the close icon and image.. please see attached edited image.
(2)if i want to make some test bold (Heads Up) how can i do that ,
(3)is changing the icon is possible? want to get exclamation mark

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because,css applied on this `text-transform: uppercase`. You need to overide this with custom CSS:

```
.react-alerts .alert .message {
    -webkit-box-flex: 3;
    -webkit-flex: 3;
    -ms-flex: 3;
    flex: 3;
    /* text-transform: uppercase; */remove this
    padding: 8px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me:

```css
 #__react-alert__ div div div {
  /* width: auto !important; */
  -webkit-box-flex: 3;
  -webkit-flex: 3;
  -ms-flex: 3;
  flex: 3;
  text-transform: initial !important;
  font:inherit !important;
  padding: 8px 10px;
}
```

- doesn't work without '!important'
- `.react-alerts .alert .message` didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [this react-alert](https://github.com/schiehll/react-alert) , then you can use the option specified in their page itself.

`alert.success(<div style={{ textTransform: 'initial' }}>Some Message</div>);`